# After installing ORO CRM /user/login throws a 404

Tags: installation, http-status-code-404, orocrm

I have, I think, successfully installed ORO CRM as far as the documentation shows. However, when I visit the root of the domain, I am immediately redirected to /user/login (which seems to be the right action).  However that page throws a 404 error.

I have changed the COMPOSER install string from `commerce-crm-application` (as listed under both OroCommerce and OroCRM) to just `crm-application`.

I have followed https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/installation/#install-for-dev and it all seemed to work, except for an error with the assets installation.  I ran `php bin/console oro:assets:install` as instructed and it completed successfully.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some issues with the webserver configuration.

Please check [the official documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/web-server-config/) for the recommended config and don't forget to restart the webserver after changes.

Comment: There was a problem with the apache SSL config file....thnaks for the heads up. Now solved and up and running.